# PHP Post vars to third party

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to take some variables in php and redirect the user to a third party site with the variables sent as post vars. I know this would probably be easier with cookies but the third party is already set up to handle posts. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple techniques you could use.  One is iterate through the POST vars and add to a form and resubmit the form perhaps using Javascript onLoad.

```
<html>
    <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
        <form action="new-location.php" method="post">
            <?php foreach( $_POST as $key => $val ): ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo htmlSpecialChars( $key, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' ) ?>" value="<?php echo htmlSpecialChars( $val, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' ) ?>">
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Another option would be to use PHP and cURL and send the data to the remote site:

```
url_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: The form on load method worked perfectly and fit in just fine with what I am doing. Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Happy to be of assistance and figured one of those two would do the trick.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

In a PHP page, open a connection to the third-party website using cURL and use this function :

```
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'field1=allo&field2=fsdfsd');
```

The third-party will receive the request with also a real POST request. You'll be able also to read the answer from the third-party website.

Comment: This is not a redirect. You can use curl to POST values to a third party site, but you will also receive the html through the PHP script, which would have to be echoed out to the user. Unless you do some manipulation to the html received, things like CSS/Javascript includes, images, and links will not work correctly.

Comment: @AndrewR The OP just want to redirect the user somewhere with POST values. Those lines do it. Also, if you don't want to read the output then just use `curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); `. I do not understand your point sir.

Comment: I understood "redirect the user to a third party site with the variables sent as post vars" as redirect the users browser to a third party site(leave his site), passing data along sent in an HTTP POST. Maybe I interpreted that incorrectly.

Comment: This is useful but AndrewR is correct that I need the user's browser to end up at the specified page as well as send the post vars.

Comment: Ah ok, I was lost. But from point A, it's possible to echo the result on the page and enforce css, js, etc path for accurate displaying.

Answer (score 0):

A post needs to be sent from the users browser. A common way to do this is to use an intermediate page which would include a form with hidden input elements containing the variables you want to post, then using Javascript to automatically submit the form on load.

Answer (score 0):

Some googling suggests that other than horrible kludges with forms, cURL is the way to go. I'm no expert, but this link http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/ and the php cURL reference should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information, but maybe you can send it using form with help of javascript (jQuery)

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#form').submit();
});
</script>
<form action="external.url/page.php" action="post" id="form">
<input type="hidden" name="variable" value="value" />
</form>
```