# How to submit a form to external website to get an XML response but display response on your website

Tags: php, xml, forms

I want to create a page where people can type in their vehicle registrations details and then be presented with more information about their car. I am using Experian for this but, I'm struggling due to my lack of XML knowledge.

Here is the form:

Now this form exists on my website. What happens is when a I enter my car reg details is it takes to me to https://www.AutomotiveMXIN.com/UAT/ and show me my car details in XML.

How can I make it so when I submit my car reg on the form I get my car data back but on my website rather than https://www.AutomotiveMXIN.com/UAT/.

Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have the form submit the data to your site, then use that data in a cURL post to the external server and manipulate the response as necessary.

edit: the answers to this question [PHP Post vars to third party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637854/php-post-vars-to-third-party) provide some concrete examples and code samples.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery to perform an ajax post to the site and get the resulting xml that way.  See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)